# Symfony 2, how to save AJAX submitted data into new entity

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

ok, I have submitted serialized data via AJAX using JQuery into a function within my Symfony 2 (2.7.10) app.

I am now having a few issues with trying to bind that data to a new entity and save that entity.

Here is what I have done to date:

```
public function AJAX_SaveTestAction(Request $request) {

    // $GetFormData = $request->get('Data'); <- This is a jquery serialized data

    $NewData = new TestInfo(); <- this is the entity I want to save

    $form = $this->createForm(new InfoType(), $NewData);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ( $request->isMethod('POST') ) {

       $form->bind( $request->get('Data') );   

         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist( $NewData ); <- not saving jquery returns 500 server error?
         $em->flush();
    }

    die(); <- this is just here for testing, I will want to return a json message or something else!
}
```

All help most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Use firebug in firefox to open the AJAX request response. So you will be able to debug it. Nobody can help we only know that you receive a 500 error.

Comment: I hate firebug, but I give that ago, I was trying to think of a way of seeing how to find what it was trying to do. But mainly I just wanted to posted, just in case someone saw I was doing something wrong and knew how to fix it. But thanks, I have a look at firebug

Comment: ok firebug its sort of call, it looks like, as it returns the HTML symfony is saying that my 1st field can not be null. so it looks like the bind is not working to well bind the data into the new form and therefore is not being saved!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use form->handleRequest and form->bind
form->bind was the equivalent of form->handleRequest before Symfony 2.6.

If you are using Symfony 2.3 use form->bind
If you are using Symfony 2.6+ use form->handleRequest

Your Controller should look like :

```
public function AJAX_SaveTestAction(Request $request) 
{
    $NewData = new TestInfo();

    $form = $this->createForm(new InfoType(), $NewData);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted()){ // if you also want to check if your entity is valid, just replace it with "if($form->isValid()){"
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $em->persist( $NewData ); 
         $em->flush();

         return new Response('It works');
    }

    return new Response('error');
}
```

But your JS should send a POST request to this route (with post parameters).

May be with that :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Cool, I have had to move on to something else with the system now but I give this ago when I can, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To bind correctly your request data to your entity using `handleRequest`, Symfony expects an array with your form name as key in your POSTed data.

If you did not override method `getName` of your form, it is defined by default by "underscoring" your Form class name. So it should be `info_type` here.

**TL;DR:** You should submit your data as `['info_type' => [ YOUR DATA... ]]` instead of just `[ YOUR DATA... ]`